# PHP array_unique returns duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table `tracks`:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                 tag|
+---+--------------------+
| 1 |              dance,|
| 2 |        dance,tecno,|
| 3 |        dance,hihop,|
| 4 |                rap,|
| 5 |            country,|
| . |                 ...|
+---+--------------------+
```

I tried this (`$value` is my query):

```
$tags = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `tag`, `id` FROM `tracks` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%s' GROUP BY `tag` DESC LIMIT %s, %s", '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', $this->db->real_escape_string($start), $per_page));

while($row = $tags->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$tags = explode(',', $row['tag']);
$rows = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $tags));

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if(stripos($row, $value) !== false) {
        $tag_output .= '<div class="hashtag-inner">
                            '.$row.'
                        </div>';
    }
}
```

From this Eg. the output expected was: `dance, tecno, hiphop, rap, country` with all unique tags instead I have multiple output for the tag `dance`. 
What's wrong with my output?

Comment: which is the value or $value  in $this->db->real_escape_string($value) ?

Comment: @scaisEdge it's the search query from the search input

Comment: `array_unique` looks at the whole string, it doesn't consider `dance,` and `dance,techno` to be duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking about that...what can I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `explode()` in the loop that processes each row. Your code is just exploding the last row.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $tags->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tags = explode(',', $row['tag']);
    $rows = array_merge($rows, $tags);
}
$rows = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', array_filter($rows)));
```

`array_filter()` is used to remove the empty strings that come from the `,` at the end of the tag lists.

However, the best long-term solution would be to normalize your database schema so you don't store comma-separated lists in the table. You should have a table where each tag is in a separate row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
$tags = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `tag`, `id` FROM `tracks` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%s' GROUP BY `tag` DESC LIMIT %s, %s", '%'.$this->db->real_escape_string($value).'%', $this->db->real_escape_string($start), $per_page));

$str = '';
while($row = $tags->fetch_assoc()) {
    // combine all tags from "tag" column
    $str .= $row['tag'];
}

$tags = explode(',', $str);
$rows = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $tags));

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if(stripos($row, $value) !== false) {
        $tag_output .= '<div class="hashtag-inner">
                            '.$row.'
                        </div>';
    }
}
```